# Android Google Maps v2: ClassNotFoundExeption: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Fist of all sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem with my sample maps activity. I think I saw thousands of topics about this problem but none of them solve my problem. I tried in all ways I found here and still nothing. Please help!

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my.package"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.my.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.my.package.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA2AofgQEL0kvT9-LL5NufV1sPlGHqKZC8" /> 
</application>    
</manifest>
```

My Main:

```
package com.my.package;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Main extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

My LogCat:

```
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:411)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2087)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at com.my.package.Main.onCreate(Main.java:13)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5236)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     ... 11 more
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4884)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     ... 20 more
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
11-08 21:55:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(8319):     ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Need to import `Google Play Services` library as a library project in your app

see this link how to import a library

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

Comment: Yep, I've imported them. I try two ways: via Properties & via Build Path. Now I have them imported by Properties but none of this methods works for me :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your fragment declaration is incorrect?  The example at http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html uses `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` instead of `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`.